# difference between didEnterRegion and didRangeBeacons

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, clbeacon, clbeaconregion

What is the exact difference between didEnterRegion and didRangeBeacons in terms of use case i mean when i should implement didEnterRegion/didExitRegion and when should i implement didRangeBeacons ?

What are the each delegate method's exact functionality  ? From apple's documentation it's not very clear.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
}
```

AND

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
               inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
}
```

Comment: i think didRangeBeacons that use for iBeacons and didEnterRegion that user we normally for getting user location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`didEnterRegion` will be called once when you cross the threshold of the region (i.e. detect the beacon).  Once you exit the region  (i.e. the beacon is no longer visible) `didExitRegion` will be called and then `didEnterRegion` will be called again if you re-enter the region.

`didRangeBeacons` is called repeatedly while beacons that you are ranging are visible, giving you updated proximity information.

A common strategy is to monitor for beacon regions and once `didEnterRegion` is called, start ranging that beacon for updates, stopping the ranging once `didExitRegion` is called.

See also  - [The Location Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1)

Comment: This is correct.  You get much more information from the `didRangeBeacons` callback, including a list of the specific beacons that are currently visible, and an estimate of the distance between the mobile device and each beacon.  All of this info is updated at a frequency of 1Hz.  If you need any of this information, you must use ranging.  If you have a simpler use case where you just need to know when you are nearby and no longer nearby a beacon or group of beacons, then use the monitoring API and the `didEnterRegion`/`didExitRegion` callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

A `CLBeaconRegion` defined with just a proximity UUID, or a proximity UUID and Major id may correspond to multiple physical beacons in your deployment (I will call these 'partially qualified regions' here).

`didEnterRegion` notifies when the device first enters the proximity of one or more beacons that match the `CLBeaconRegion`, but does not detail which matching beacons are nearby. `didExitRegion` is only called when all matching beacons go out of range.

There are two uses for ranging beacons once a region has been entered:

1. To get details of the nearby beacons that correspond to a partially qualified region.

This information is provided to `didRangeBeacons` as an array of `CLBeacon` objects. Note that the set of beacons can change over time without the device leaving the region and receiving a `didExitRegion` (as long as at least one matching beacon is within range, the device is in the region). This means that applications that use partially qualified regions but still care about the specific beacons need to process the repeated invocations of `didRangeBeacons`.

2. To get the proximity information provided in the `CLBeacon` objects.

This may be relevant even if fully qualified regions are used. As proximity changes when the device moves within the region the repeated invocations of `didRangeBeacons` need to be processed.